# How to repeat every character of a given String in java?

Tags: java, string

How to repeat every character of a given String in java?

For example:

```
String s = "Hello";
```

Becomes:

```
s = "HHeelllloo";
```

Comment: Hint: Use a StringBuilder and a `for` loop. And you know the size of the resultant string in advance.

Comment: What your teacher wants you to do is to [read the documentation of the string class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), find the methods which could help you to solve this problem and combine them in the right way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use regex!

```
s = s.replaceAll(".", "$0$0");
```

OK, so how does this work?

The `replaceAll()` method takes a regex as the search term, and a dot matches every character. So every character will be replaced.

The replacement term can contain *back references* to captured groups, which are coded as `$n`, where `n` is 1-9. But there's a special *implicit* group zero that is the *entire* match, so `$0$0` means "the whole match twice".

Overall, in English this means "replace every character with two copies of itself".

Comment: plus one; smart puppy.

Comment: You won't help the OP to learn java when you just give them a solution they can't understand without any explanation.

Comment: No but the answer is a good one. Close the question, don't downvote the answer.

Comment: @Bathsheba no, I will not remove my downvote. "this answer is not useful" as the tooltip says.

Comment: It's probably the safest way of solving the problem given the extremely light maintenance burden. Albeit not the fastest.

Comment: Can anyone explain this answer how it works? I don't think this is the right answer for a question. But something is there it seems.

Comment: The `StringBuilder` suggestion will actually be quicker.

Comment: Say no to spoon feeding, agreed with Philipp!

Comment: @kumar see answer for an explanation of how it works.

Comment: @phil see edited answer for an explanation of how it works. Using the JDK's API and how to use it to minimise the amount of code you write *is* learning the language.